# How to define values specific to a connection of two nodes in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I have two types in my schema:

```
type Resident = {            type Visitor = {
  id                           id
  name                         name
}                            }
```

In my database:

Residents and Visitors Tables:

```
+--------+-------+   +--------+---------+
| res_id | name  |   | vis_id | name    |
+--------+-------+   +--------+---------+
|  1     | Alice |   |  1     | Charlie |
|  2     | Bob   |   +--------+---------+
+--------+-------+
```

And then a table that shows which visitor belongs to which resident:

```
+--------+--------+--------------+
| res_id | vis_id | relationship |
+--------+--------+--------------+
|      1 |      1 | fam/fri      |
|      2 |      1 | contractor   |
+--------+--------+--------------+
```

Each visitor could either be a "fam/fri" or a "contractor" to a resident. So Charlie is Alice's visitor as her family or friend. However, Charlie is also a visitor to Bob, but instead as a contractor.

**Question**: How do I structure my schema so that when I query Alice, Charlie returns as a fam/fri, and when I query Bob, Charlie is returned as a contractor? I imagine this:

```
{
  Resident(id: 1) {             "Resident" {
    name                           "Alice"
    Visitor {                      "Visitor" {
      id                ===>          "1"
      name                            "Charlie"
      relationship                    "fam/fri"
    }                              }
  }                             }
}
```

and also:

```
{
  Resident(id: 2) {             "Resident" {
    name                           "Bob"
    Visitor {                      "Visitor" {
      id                ===>          "1"
      name                            "Charlie"
      relationship                    "contractor"
    }                              }
  }                             }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Are you asking how to write the SQL query to obtain that result? Are you asking how to structure your schema to be able to make the queries above?

Comment: Sorry, I just edited the question, but I meant how to organize my schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
type Query {
  resident(id: Int): Resident
}

type Resident {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
  visitors: [Visitor!]!
}

type Vistor {
  id: Int!
  name: String!
  relationship: VisitorRelationship!
}

enum VisitorRelationship {
  CONTRACTOR
  FAMILY_OR_FRIEND
}
```

Note that by convention field names should be **camelCase** and type names should be in **PascalCase**. If the data returned from your data source (whether that's a database, API, or whatever) is not in the same shape as what you want to return from your GraphQL service, then you should transform the data before returning it inside your resolver, for example:

```
const relationshipMap = {
  'fam/fri': 'FAMILY_OR_FRIEND',
  'contractor': 'CONTRACTOR',
}

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    resident: (root, args) => {
      const resident = await Resident.findById(args.id)
      // assuming resident has a property named joinTable that's
      // an array and each relationship has a property named visitor
      return {
        ...resident,
        visitors: resident.joinTable.map(relationship => {
          return {
            ...joinTable.visitor,
            relationship: relationshipMap[joinTable.relationship],
          }
        })
      }
    },
  },
}
```

You can also map enums to custom values [this way](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars/#enums).

Comment: Thank you. You answered exactly what I asked and that makes sense, but now I don't undertand how to write the resolvers to change the values of relationship depending on the Resident parent of Visitor. Could you explain here? Or should I make another question?

Comment: @dannyvelasquez I edited my answer to include an example, but that really depends on how you're getting the resident and the related rows. If you still can't figure it out from that, then post another question with your updated schema and the resolver code.